# Get last node in XML using DOMDocument PhP

Tags: php, dom

I've made a class that reads value and node name of value and combines it into array to use it as a simple and quick access to config in XML. But this solution works only if ill give bottom node, XML looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<settings>
<const>
    <inscript>true</inscript>
    <title>Template</title>
</const>
<meta>
</meta>
<db>
    <user>user</user>
    <pass>pass</pass>
    <host>host</host>
    <name>name</name>
</db>
<path>
    <style>
        <css>/Template/view/www/style/</css>
        <img>/Template/view/www/style/img</img>
    </style>
</path>
</settings>
```

Now I want to get for example whole db node and return it as an array where node name wold be the key and node value, value. but im stuck at this. Heres what i made so far.

```
class config {

private static $xml = "lib/config/settings.xml";
private static $xmlRoot = "settings";

public static function loadConfig($value) {
    $domDocument = new DOMDocument();

    $domDocument->load(self::$xml);
    $settings = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName(self::$xmlRoot);

    try {
        foreach ($settings as $setting) {
            $configValue = $setting->getElementsByTagName($value)->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $configNode = $setting->getElementsByTagName($value)->item(0)->nodeName;

            $test = $setting->getElementsByTagName("path")->item(0)->childNodes->item(2)->nodeName;

            var_dump($test);

        }

        $configValue = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $configValue)));
        $configNode = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $configNode)));

        $configArray = array_combine($configNode, $configValue);

        return $configArray;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo '<h1>Błąd - '.$e->getMessage().'</h1>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Although in most cases I prefer the `DOM` extension, it seems that [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is better suited for this purpose. You'll not need to parse the node data into the array yourself. Have a look at the manual and examples...

Comment: Why are you doing a `foreach` on the root element? There's only one root element.

Comment: I wanted to try DOMDocument for php, just to learn it. And foreach iterates on all nodes in root I think.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz I suggested `simplexml` just because of the special purpose that you need the whole node as array. Of course it would be possible with `DOM` too, but in this case `simplexml` is as its aims to be: simpler, because less code

Comment: Ill probably remake it to simplexml if there will be no other way, Its just an experiment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XPath like this:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($domDocument);

$config = array();
foreach ($xp->query('./db/*') as $node) {
        $config[$node->nodeName] = $node->textContent;
}

return $config;
```

Comment: Sweet with little modification it will cover all my needs :) thank you.